# .getNumPages() method of PyPDF2 Python library returns total number of pages in a pdf as 0

Tags: python, pypdf

I want to retrieve the text from the pdf files but using this code, I get the total number of pages as 0. How should I improve so as to get the correct total pages in a pdf?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of pages with pypdf (PyPDF2 is deprecated):

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
number_of_pages = len(reader.pages)
```

Answer (score 0):

(disclaimer: I am the author of `pText`, the library used in this answer.)

As an alternative to `pypdf2` you could also try `pText`.

1.Load the `Document`

```
with open("input.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file_handle:
    doc = PDF.loads(pdf_file_handle)
```

2.Get the `DocumentInfo`

```
    doc_info = doc.get_document_info()
    number_of_pages = doc_info.get_number_of_pages()
```

You can obtain pText either on [GitHub](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ptext-release), or using [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/ptext-joris-schellekens/) There are a ton more [examples](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/ptext-release/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md), check them out to find out more about working with images.

Answer (score 0):

**.pages** method helps to do it

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
    
# Read the pdf
reader = PdfReader("US_Declaration.pdf")

# Find total number of pages
readpdf = len(reader.pages)
```

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.